# How to add shortcut for Xfce Application Menu

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce, appmenu

I have XFCE in my desktop, and I want to make a keyboard shortcut for Super_L and Super_R ( Known as Windows Keys ) to open my Applications Menu.

What is the command?

[image: Xfce Application Menu]

[image: Xfce Keyboard Application Shortcuts]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**14.04 and newer**

```
xfce4-popup-whiskermenu
```

**12.04**

```
xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that it worked in xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu. You helped me found it.

Comment: I just booted up my 12.04 to find it for older releases, which I guessed from your screenshot. :)

Comment: You are awesome. :)

Comment: Anyone know why it isn't set to the super key by default?

Comment: @extremeaxe5 On Windows I've pressed the super key by accident countless times while in game / watching a film / etc. and I find it one of the most annoying features of Windows. I'm guessing I'm not alone with this. Also, I think the super key is like CTRL or ALT, it's meant to be used in combination with other keys. Imagine binding the menu to CTRL!

Comment: As of right now `xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu` works with debian trixie/sid while the other command doesn't.