# "Windows" key not opening "start menu" on Ubuntu Studio 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04, xfce, ubuntu-studio

It used to be in Linux Mint or an older version of Ubuntu, that if I hit my <kbd>Super</kbd> Key it would open up a "start menu".

I took a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve by hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/492856/how-to-add-shortcut-for-xfce-application-menu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to *Settings* > *Keyboard* > *Application Shortcuts*. You should see an entry called "**xfce4-popup-whiskermenu**".

Change its shortcut to <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

Comment: Mine is defaulted out of the box as `CTRL + ESC` ... I'm good with that. Thanks for letting me know what to look for (that whiskermenu thing).

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 settings don't have an "Application Shortcuts" section

Comment: @Alkanshel Are you using Xfce desktop environment (which was the default DE of Ubuntu Studio 18.04)? This question is specifically about Ubuntu *Studio* 18.04.